# Create a 3D Plot of a piece of Fusilli pasta

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to plot a [fusilli pasta](http://www.theculinaryexchange.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/fusilli-pasta-types.jpg)-like surface. I have seen such a *Mathematica*-made surface before:

[image]

So far, I am able to create normal helical surfaces in the following way:

```
l = 2;
ParametricPlot3D[{0.1*u Sin[l*t], 0.1*u Cos[l*t], t/(2*Pi)}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, {u, -1, 1}]
```

which produces

[image]

My question is: How can I build a fusilli helix out of that?

Comment: How do you want the output to be different?  What about this ouput:  `l = 2;
ParametricPlot3D[{0.1*u Sin[l*t], 0.1*u Cos[l*t], t/(2*\[Pi])}, {t, 0,
   2*\[Pi]}, {u, -1, 1}, Extrusion -> .02, Mesh -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]`

Comment: Have you tried combining three helices with a phase shift using `Show`? I think that's the output you wanted, right?

Comment: @MB1965 - I missed that there were multiple helices in the pasta (also I think fusili often has those little grooves which hold onto the sauce so well).

Comment: @JasonB. I had to look twice myself. Do you know of any simple edit to the parametrization to get grooves in? Must be possible but I can't think of it.

Comment: @MB1965 - one way to do that would be to replace mesh lines with tubes: http://i.stack.imgur.com/miJq4.png

Comment: You might be interested in *[Pasta by Design](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0500515808)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is already almost what you need. You just have to combine three surfaces like yours into the same plot - with two slight modifications: The radius `u` should only go from 0 to 1 and the phase of the two other surfaces has to be shifted by `2/3*Pi` and `4/3*Pi`, respectively:

```
l = 2;
ParametricPlot3D[{{0.1*u Sin[l*t], 0.1*u Cos[l*t],t/(2*\[Pi])},
                  {0.1*u Sin[l*t + 2/3*Pi], 0.1*u Cos[l*t + 2/3*Pi], t/(2*\[Pi])},
                  {0.1*u Sin[l*t + 4/3*Pi], 0.1*u Cos[l*t + 4/3*Pi], t/(2*\[Pi])}
                 }, {t, 0, 2*\[Pi]}, {u, 0, 1}]
```

This yields:

[image: Plot of a fussili]

Comment: This is essentially the same so I won't post separate answer, feel free to include it. `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Table[
   RotationTransform[l + off, {0, 0, 1}]@{r, r, l},
   {off, {0, 2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}}]
 , {r, 0, 1}
 , {l, 0, 10}
 ]`

Comment: +1 - if you want it to be more pasta-like, you can use the undocumented `Extrusion` option, and give each surface the same `PlotStyle`, you can get something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NURfk.png) with your code.

Comment: @JasonB. I had no idea `Extrusion` existed. Where'd you find it?

Comment: @MB1965 I found it on this site, some question about adding thickness to a `ContourPlot3D`

Comment: @MB1965 Also `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"` which is documented.

Comment: @Edmund right, I saw that one. I'm just always curious how people find out about undocumented things. It's interesting to see how the system works and what we can find out about it.